# ApiFilter - Altername parameter name

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

Is it possible to have an alternate parameter name for the URL?

I have something like

```
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, strategy="exact", properties={
 *     "appcountryref.countryname":"exact",
 *     "refyear":"exact"
 * })
```

Which lead to an url lile
https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/exo/allowances?appcountryref.countryname=Belgium&page=1

I would like to have:
https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/exo/allowances?countryname=Belgium&page=1

The API linking the "countryname" to "appcountryref.countryname" behind the scene

Is it possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information from Grégoire Hébert Contributor and tutor

> It is not expected because it reflects the structure of your public data.
>   If you want to do it you need private property whose getter returns the value of the child object but this is not a good practice.
>   It's not trivial if it's done this way, it's to meet standards